# Variable undefined when using Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I want to make alternative way for making stored procedures by using Doctrine but I am stuck, could any one help me?

### Example stored procedure to be formed:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE catalog_get_department_details(IN DepartmentName)
    BEGIN
    SELECT name, description
    FROM
    department
    WHERE name = name;
```

### Departments Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\departmentsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="departments")
 */
class departments
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $department_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="categories",mappedBy="departments")
     */
    private $categories;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getDepartmentId()
    {
        return $this->department_id;
    }

    public function setDepartmentId($department_id)
    {
        $this->department_id = $department_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $description
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }
```

The scenario is when the route is **/index/departmentname/Regional** ;
my **DefaultController** will capture **Regional** as parameter

### DefaultController:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route ("/index/department/{department_name}")
     */
    function departmentAction($department_name)
    {
        // accessing departmentsRepository 
        $categoriesRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:departments');
        $categoriesRepository->getDepartmentDetails($department_name);
    }
```

### departmentsRepository:

```
class departmentsRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    function getDepartmentDetails($departmentName)
    {
        $em=$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:departments');
        $qb=$em->createQueryBuilder('dep');
        $qb->select('dep.name','dep.description');
        $qb->where("dep.name=$departmentName");
```

When I call `var_dump($qb->getDQL());die;` it shows me exactly what I want:

> SELECT dep.name, dep.description FROM AppBundle\Entity\departments dep WHERE dep.name=Regional

I then execute it by calling

```
$qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

But I receive the following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 86 near 'Regional': Error: 'Regional'
>   is not defined.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dep.name` value isn't being escaped.  You would expect the query to look like this instead:

```
WHERE dep.name='Regional'
```

But what you should be doing, and what is safer, is binding that to a parameter, like so:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:departments');
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('dep');
$qb->select('dep.name', 'dep.description');
$qb->where("dep.name = :departmentName");
$qb->setParameter('departmentName', $departmentName);
```

Doctrine will handle the escaping for you, and safely.  This also allows you to avoid SQL injection attacks.  Also since you are already in your `departments` repository you should be able to use the `_em` value as a shortcut, and also not have to re-specify the departments entity, like so:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder('dep');
$qb->select('dep.name', 'dep.description');
$qb->where("dep.name = :departmentName");
$qb->setParameter('departmentName', $departmentName);
```

Side not, in your controller action you are calling the repository function but not actually saving the results to any variable.